# x86-64 Gas macro cant use ' for arguments ('\arg') how do i do it

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, x86-64, gnu-assembler

```
.macro  testch  ch, quote #i have to do it through this macro to get ' in

    .ifeq   \quote\ch\quote - 95
    

    .else

    .endif
.endm

//my macro
.macro  mtest   arg

    .irpc   a, \arg
    
    # i cant do .ifeq '\a' on its own doing it with the above macro works
    testch  \a, "'" # .ifeq '\a' - 95
#cant do movq $'\a', %rdx etc too, could with a macro like above

    .endr
.endm
```

i dont know how to google my question.
when i look at the macro expansion with -alm it seems that it thinks i want '\'

ive tried (\'arg\') ('(\arg)') ('\()\arg') ("'"\arg"'") etc alot of combinations of random stuff that ive read in the macro part of manual that could help with conflicting stuff. it works when i substitute with a second macro but i dont like it and wondering if there is a way to do it properly on the line. thanks

it seems as soon as i type a ' it evaluates immediately what is to the right of it and it doesnt even look for the closing ' .something like that is happening i think

Comment: *t seems as soon as i type a ' it evaluates immediately what is to the right of it and it doesnt even look for the closing '* - Yes, that's consistent with what I've seen with stuff like `mov $'a, %eax` (AT&T syntax for x86 to load the immediate constant `'a'`).  Trying to do `mov $'abcd', %eax` (the equivalent of which works in NASM) results in `backward ref to unknown label "97:"` like it's taking the `ab` part as `97b`, a label reference.  `97` is the ASCII code `'a'`.  So GAS's parser *really* doesn't care about useful error messages in this case!

Comment: so is there a way to do '\arg' without that macro? i dont even know why that macro even works (got to enclose the ' between "'s) i just keep doing random crap out of frustration lol

Comment: No idea, I don't usually use GAS macros, sorry.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but if you want to detect an underscore then use `.ifc "\a","_"`

Comment: oh thanks that was what i want to do in that instance. but also there is the case if i want to do movq $'\a', %rdx etc cant do movq $"\a", %rdx do u know a way?